# Typescript Multilingual Interfaces Implementation

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface, multilingual

I am using MongoDB, NodeJS & React-Native to build an app.
Since I wanted everything to be available in 2 languages (English & Hebrew in my case),
I used i18n-next in my RN app to have all texts in my app in both languages.

My database is where it gets tricky, there are string fields which I need to have in both languages (like name for an item), so I made a Typescript type called MultilingualString, which just has a language code field for each of my supported languages, and used it as these field's type.

```js
type MultilingualString = {
    en: string,
    he: string
};
```

The issue is that once I get the data into my RN app, I want to determine the wanted language and transform all those fields into a simple string field in the wanted language, so that it will be simple to access and use it through out the app's components.

To tackle that, I made a generic recursive function that takes an Object and checks its keys one by one, for every key that is a MultilingualString, it takes the value of the wanted language key code and sets it as the original key's value.

```js
async function determineObjectLanguage<T extends Object>(object: T): Promise<T> {
    currentLanguageCode = "en"; // Might be "he" or "en", simplified for the example

    for (let key of Object.keys(object)) {
        const tKey = key as keyof T; 

        if (isMultilingualString(object[tKey])) {
            object[tKey] = object[tKey][currentLanguageCode as keyof MultilingualString];
        } 
        else if (isObject(object[tKey])) {
            object[tKey] = await determineObjectLanguage(object[tKey] as Object, currentLanguageCode) as T[keyof T];
        }
    }

    return object;
}

export const isMultilingualString = (value: any): value is MultilingualString => {
    return (value instanceof Object) && ("en" in value) && ("he" in value);
}
```

The problem is that to be able to get along with Typescript through that I had to set all of those fields to be of type 'MultilingualString | string', which basically means big trouble later on with the type safety on these.

To clarify, I want to store objects in my database like this:

```js
export interface Item {
    name: MultilingualString
    description: MultilingualString,
    ...
}
```

Then parse them in my app in to this:

```js
export interface Item {
    name: string
    description: string,
    ...
}
```

That way I pass it on to my components as if it was always locale, allowing me to ignore the multilingual implementation everywhere else besides when loading and parsing it from the server for the first time.

The question is how can I achieve the described functionality in a both elegant and type-safe way?
Am I going about this all wrong?

Would appreciate any tips and recommendations guys, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know the best approaches for multilanguage are:

**Have default language**, to which any untranslated text will be forwarded to. For example, you won't translate the 'MB' for Mega-bytes in most languages.

**Access the object** by the locale. it's best to let the translated text be returned dynamically.

So in your case, I will do something like this.

*I'm providing a short version, of course, you will have to import the JSON files or objects for the locale*

```js
export default class I18Translation {
    private static defaultLocale = 'en';

    private static locales = {
        en: {
            "hello": "Hello",
            "mb"   : "MB"
        },
        he: {
            "hello": "שלום",
        }
    }

    public static locale(text: string, locale: string): string {
        // First try to get to required
        if (this.locales[locale][text] !== undefined) {
            return this.locales[locale][text];
        }
        // If not we would go for the default
        if (this.locales[this.defaultLocale][text] !== undefined) {
            return this.locales[this.defaultLocale][text];
        }

        // Eventuality if we don't have any translation will just return 
        // the text as is
        return text;
    }

    // This is a short version of the same function
      public static localeShort(text: string, locale: string): string {
        return this.locales[locale][text] !== undefined ?
            this.locales[locale][text]
            : this.locales[defaultLocale][text] !== undefined ?
                this.locales[defaultLocale][text]
                : text;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for helping out!
If I understand your answer correctly, I should use the 'locale' function every time I want to access a multilingual property. In my example I tried to replace multilingual values for an entire object with the locale texts at once, then when I access properties later on in my components I simply access the 'name' key as if it is a simple string.

Comment: Perhaps your approach was better looking back, but now I'd have to refactor all of my components to use it that way. Ideally at this point I'd want to have 2 variations for each of my objects interfaces, one multilingual and one local, and have a function that will parse it from one to the other, applying the local values for each property. For example I'd have Item interface & MultilingualItem interface. The second will be stored in the database and when queried I'll parse it to the first and pass on to my components as a locale object

Comment: 1. Yes as you anyhow don't have any code completion for it, so that way you can also start using the `locale` function before you even translated it yet.

2. Yes you will have to refactor the whole thing 
That's why is need to know what is your current implementation.

Comment: I thought it over and you are just right, this approach is way better, elegant & type safe. I made a mistake with mine, trying to translate a whole object as it is loaded from the server. For convenience purposes of my own app I made a react hook that returns the translation function itself and now I'm handling a pretty huge refactor to properly use it everywhere.
Thanks a lot again :)